# Query performance of searching pattern

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search, sql-like, patindex

I have the following sample data for understanding the requirement.

Table:

```
create table ft_test
(
    col1 int identity(1,1),
    col2 varchar(max)
);

insert into ft_test values('John A Henry');
insert into ft_test values('Dsouza mak Dee');
insert into ft_test values('Smith Ashla Don');
```

**Edit**:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_test_Col1 ON ft_test(col1);

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftcat
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON ft_test  
(col2 LANGUAGE 1033)  
KEY INDEX UIX_test_Col1  
ON ftcat  
WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM
```

Notes:

> 1. Search for the given pattern in the given column of the table.
> 2. I have more than 200 millions of records in the table.
> 3. Created FULLTEXT index on required column.

Looking for best performing search query.

Givens:

> 1. Pattern: `oh`
> 2. Column to  Search: `col2`

Expected Output:

```
col1    col2
----------------------
1       John A Henry
```

Try:

1. Using FULLTEXT Index: `CONTAINS`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE CONTAINS(col2, '"*oh*"')
   ```

No output.

2. Using FULLTEXT Index: `FREETEXT`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE FREETEXT(col2, '"*oh*"')
   ```

No output.

3. Using Pattern Index: `PATINDEX`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE PATINDEX('%oh%',col2)>0
   ```

Got an output.

Execution Plan: `Table Scan`

4. Using character expression: `CHARINDEX`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE CHARINDEX('oh',col2)>0
   ```

Got an output.

Execution Plan: `Table Scan`

5. Using `LIKE`.

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE col2 LIKE '%oh%'
   ```

Got an output.

Execution Plan: `Table Scan`

Comment: You should read this Paul White's article - [Trigram Wildcard String Search in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search)

Comment: I think fulltext should give you the best results since all other options are non-seargable. I haven't worked with fulltext for a very long time but you should be able to get the results you want. Perhaps try to change the search pattern. Try `CONTAINS(col2, 'oh')`

Comment: @ZoharPeled is correct. You don't use wildcards with `CONTAINS`. Wildcard operators are for functions like `LIKE` and `PATINDEX`. [CONTAINS (Transact-SQL) - Using CONTAINS with <simple_term>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#a-using-contains-with-simpleter).

Comment: (the same is also true for `FREETEXT`: [FREETEXT (Transact-SQL) - Using FREETEXT to search for words containing specified character values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#a-using-freetext-to-search-for-words-containing-specified-character-values).)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was asked again here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226318/query-performance-of-searching-pattern